# Why does the SASC compiler not like the § symbol

Tags: sass

Why does the SASC compiler not like the § symbol?

Ordinary .css = no problem, but .sasc it throws an error?

I can even place it inside a .css comment and the compiler still throws an error

```
/* § */
```

SASC compiler likes '\00a7' just dandy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the charset at the very beginning of the file you’re trying to compile:

```
@charset “UTF-8”;
```